# Does Begin Transaction With No commit affects all sources of data entries

Tags: sql-server, transactions

If I run Begin Transaction in Query Analyzer in Sql server 2005 on live database,
where data is coming from application; Does this affect on incoming data from application or will affect only those queries that I've ran from query analyzer.
Whether data coming from application will committed automatically or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Begin Transaction` only applies to your current query context.   It doesn't affect queries coming from other users, other applications, or even other windows/tabs/connections that you may have open at the time.